# Is this the correct syntax for auto properties?

Tags: c#, automatic-properties

I've been programming for so long its hard to keep up with language changes sometimes...

Is it really ok to set properties like this after .net v2

```
    public string LocaleName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Not requiring an inner field? Seems like the compiler takes care of this lately?

Comment: You might change your question to reflect that your asking which version of C# you have installed.

Comment: that is correct and you can limit the accesiobility of each if needed E.g. public string LocaleNam { get; private set;}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is a new feature in C# 3.0

Comment: So I amn programming in C# v3, but using the .net v2 framework?

Comment: @JL, yes, it's a *C#* feature that doesn't require any specific framework version. :)

Comment: It's more of a compiler feature with Visual Studio 2008. If you're using VS2005 with .NET 3.0 extensions, you would not get this feature.

Comment: @280Z28 A C# feature may or may not need CLR support e.g. LINQ to 'X' does need CLR support whereas auto implemented properties don't because they are purely a compiler trick.

Comment: This feature requires the C# 3 compiler.

Comment: Cool, thanks Andrew - good point, its all about how it gets compiled

Comment: @solutionYogi LINQ does require the same version of the CLR as auto properties (v2) it's syntactic sugar in both cases. There was no change to the CLR going from c#v2 to C#v3

Comment: The term for this is syntactic sugar - the compiler is just making the syntax easier but the generated IL is actually still using an inner field.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine as long as you don't need to do any checking to see if the values are set the right way.

You might take a look at the [C# Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645596(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, you can also do something like this:

```
public string MyString
{
   get;
   private set;
}
```

which gives you a public accessor but a private setter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are called ['auto implemented properties'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). Compiler will create a backing field for your property.

Because 'auto implemented properties' are 'C# compiler trick', you can use them in your code and target .NET framework 2.0, as long as you use C# 3.0 compiler to compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're called [automatic properties](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/12/04/c-3-0-features-automatic-properties.aspx), and will generate the backing field behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.